# The .equals() method doesnt seem to be working right for me

Tags: java, string

I need to print "Enter number or X to close" and have a user input. I need it to detect whether that input is a string or an int. I make the input a string and then parse the int but the .equals() method isn't detecting if its an X, b/c if i enter any other letter or string it terminates it, I want it to only terminate with X or x.

My friend tells me to try a switch statement but idk how id do that, I've tried parsing a string.

```
while(input.hasNextInt()){
           String x = input.nextLine();
           if ("x".equals("Exit")||x.equals("x")) {
               System.out.print("Exiting...");
               System.exit(0);
           }
           numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(x));
           Collections.sort(numbers);
           for (int i=0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
               System.out.print(numbers.get(i)+" ");
           }
```

Enter Number or X to close: 4
4 
Average: 4.0, Median: 4, This is your min : 4, This is your max : 4

Enter Number: q

^It terminates when i enter any other letter or string

Comment: `"x".equals("Exit")` will always be `false`. `"x"` is not the same as `x`.

Comment: i get rid of that and it changes nothing

Comment: This sounds like a great time to start learning [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Chances are, `x` isn't what you think it is (or even being checked when you think it is).

Comment: What is numbers?

Comment: I debug the program and it brings me to a stack called Premain$1.transform(ClassLoader, String, Class<?>, ProtectionDomain, byte[]) line: 45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is

```
while(input.hasNextInt())
```

if you enter `x` or any other non-number, `hasNextInt` returns `false` and your `while`-loop ends.

Comment: .hasNextLine()?

Comment: Enter Number or X to close: Exit
Exiting...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Exit"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at idkm8.Statistics.get(Statistics.java:21)
 at idkm8.Main.main(Main.java:10)

Comment: @CalebFoster `For input string: "Exit"`. You shouldn't reach `parseInt` if you changed `"x".equals("Exit")` to `x.equals("Exit")` as suggested in the comments to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not accepting string input because you have while condition that accepts only int values.

```
    while(input.hasNextInt())
```

You can try changing it to -

```
    while(input.hasNext()){

    }
```

also you can try to change if condition as below-

```
    if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("x")){
            // your code here
    }
```

if you want to also exit program for "exit" you can add that to if condition like-

```
    if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("x") || x.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"){
           // your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(input.hasNext()){
           String x = input.nextLine();
           if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")||x.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
               System.out.print("Exiting...");
               System.exit(0);
           }
           numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(x));
           Collections.sort(numbers);
           for (int i=0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
               System.out.print(numbers.get(i)+" ");
           }
```

Got it to work, it was the while loop

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with equals method. You should use `input.hasNext()` instead of `input.hasNextInt()`.

It is also a good idea to check for equality on the string rather than the variable.
Try this

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String x = input.nextLine();
            if ("Exit".equals(x) || "x".equals(x)) {
                System.out.print("Exiting...");
                input.close();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(x));
            Collections.sort(numbers);
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
                System.out.print(numbers.get(i) + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Tip: always initialize resources inside a try block if using Java 7 or higher, and explicitly close it if you know when.

Comment: Closing a `Scanner` linked to `System.in` can close `System.in`, which is bad. If you didn't open a resource, don't close it.

Comment: "*It is also a good idea to check for equality on the string rather than the variable*" - curious, why?

Comment: @Fureeish In case the variable is null, we will get a NullPointerException.

Comment: That can be relevant at times, but I don't see that as a universal guideline yet.

Comment: @Fureeish true. Hence "it is a good idea" and not "you must always"

Answer (score 0):

I made your code to work as well :

```
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        String x = input.nextLine();
        if (x.equals("Exit") || x.equals("x")) {
            numbers.stream().sorted().forEach(
                (number) -> System.out.print(number + " "));
            System.out.print("Exiting...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        try { // If the entered value isn't a number.
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(x));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("The next value : " + x + "isn't a number. It wasn't added in the list");
        }
    }
```

Then the results if enter this in the terminal while the app is running :

1. First case with enterring 11 22 33 and Exit :

   11
   22
   33
   Exit     =>
   11 22 33 Exiting...
2. Second case with only x and nothing else :

   x     =>
   Exiting...
3. With a bad value "aa" :

   11
   22
   aa
   The next value : aaisn't a number. It wasn't added in the list
   33
   x     =>

   11 22 33 Exiting...